# Code coverage ignoring VueJS component files despite tests being successfully run for those components

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, webstorm, code-coverage, vue-test-utils

I am trying to get the code coverage results for my frontend application, built in VueJS. Apparently, if I create a component and then write a test (snapshot test) for that component, the IDE (WebStorm) ignores that file.

I have done some research and found out that the code coverage lists only files that contain executable JavaScript. In my case, if I create a component and just return from the component like this:

```
<template>
   ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'CustomButton',
        props: ['someText'],
        data() {
            return {};
        },
    };
</script>
```

it will work and will display `100% lines covered` in the IDE.

If I remove the `data`

```
<template>
   ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'CustomButton',
        props: ['someText'],
    };
</script>
```

then the test is ignored by the coverage, even if the snapshot test completed successfully.

As mention, I am using Jest to run all my tests, using the following configuration:

```
"jest": {
        "setupFiles": [
            "jest-localstorage-mock"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "vue"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
            ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
            "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
        },
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "jest-serializer-vue"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
            "**/tests/unit/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
        ],
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/src/**"
        ],
        "testURL": "http://localhost/",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!vue-spinner|vue-quill-editor)"
        ]
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this apart from this hacky solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you use for testing? Jest? How does your configuration file look like?

Comment: Hello @EkaterinaPrigara! Yes, I am using jest and I just edited the question with the jest configuration that I have.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is tracked at [WEB-38769](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38769), please vote for it to be notified on any progress

Comment: Thank you! I have voted for it so I'll keep an eye on it from now on.